# insert_record(); Error writing to database

Tags: moodle

I created new table in moodle by phpmyadmin.
Now I want to insert data into new table "dev".
I got ***Error writing to database***.
my code is...

```
if($_POST['send']){
    $id =$_POST['id'];
    $name =$_POST['name'];
    global $DB;
    $data = new stdClass();
    $data->dev_id  = $id;
    $data->dev_name = $name;
    $DB->insert_record('dev', $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer:

Is the `dev` table called `mdl_dev`?

Long answer:

Switch on debugging during development, this will give you a more detailed error message:

https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Debugging

In your `config.php` add this:

```
// Developer settings - not for production or staging!
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

$CFG->debug = E_ALL | E_STRICT; // 32767;
$CFG->debugdisplay = true;
```

Also, you should use the XMLDB editor for creating tables :

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/XMLDB_editor

Also never user $_POST directly, this can introduce SQL injection. Always use optional_param() or required_param() - for example:

```
$send = optional_param('send', false, PARAM_BOOL);
$id = optional_param('id', null, PARAM_INT);
$name = optional_param('name', null, PARAM_TEXT);
if ($send) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. Now I have modified as you say $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

There are different possibilities. It's hard to tell without knowing the database structure and the data contained inside.

1: The table doesn't exist. As Russell England said, make sure the table mdl_dev exists.

2: The table has some required fields that you didn't assign to your $data-Object and there's no default defined.

3: One of the fields is unique and the value that you've passed to your $data-object for that field is already used in the table by a different data set.

4: The data types that you pass to the table don't match the type that's defined for your table field, such as trying to save a string in an INT field.

5: Your values exceed the allowed range, such as the name being longer than the defined maximum length for that field.

Comment: I check again my table as you say. Thank you so much.